# Admin login error: Access denied

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, admin-panel, administration

I have installed magento on one of my site but I am not able to login in to the admin of site. Database table 'admin_user' is empty. It give me error:

```
    Access denied.
```

[image]

How can login into admin of site?

What I already did:

1. Imported table 'admin_user' from local and inserted data on live database. It didn't work.
2. Gone through these links: http://www.crucialwebhost.com/kb/how-to-reset-your-magento-password/, https://wiki.magento.com/display/m1wiki/Resetting+the+admin+Password
3. Checked https://magento.stackexchange.com/ questions related to admin login issue.

Error produce:

1. I created a database and imported sample data into it.
2. Install a fresh magento site and after installing I used database created in 1st step and all these are on same hosting.

Details:

1. Fresh magento version 1.9.2.1
2. Sample data version used 1.9.0.0
3. I have to do this because I could not install magento on sample database table.
4. Front-end working fine except few images are not displaying but thats not a issue here.

Anyone might have faced such issue or may face sometime. So what are the ways to login to admin of site?

Comment: Do you have data in  "admin_role" table ? Any record with role name as "Administrators"?

Comment: No. though i added myself but this table was empty.

Comment: You could create an admin user with magerun if you have it installed

Comment: @RobbieAverill How? 

I already done. please check my 1st step under "What I already did:"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the admin_rule table there should be an entry with record

```
INSERT INTO `admin_rule` (`rule_id`, `role_id`, `resource_id`, `privileges`, `assert_id`, `role_type`, `permission`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'all', NULL, 0, 'G', 'allow');
```

For admin_role table

```
INSERT INTO `admin_role` (`role_id`, `parent_id`, `tree_level`, `sort_order`, `role_type`, `user_id`, `role_name`, `gws_is_all`, `gws_websites`, `gws_store_groups`) VALUES
(1, 0, 1, 1, 'G', 0, 'Administrators', 1, NULL, NULL);
```

And create one admin user from root file using below script and try to login with that detail and see if that work.

```
<?php

# Create New admin User programmatically.
require_once('./app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app();

try {
    $user = Mage::getModel('admin/user')
            ->setData(array(
                'username' => 'admin1',
                'firstname' => 'Admin',
                'lastname' => 'Admin',
                'email' => 'admin@test.com',
                'password' => 'admin123',
                'is_active' => 1
            ))->save();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

//Assign Role Id
try {
    $user->setRoleIds(array(1))  //Administrator role id is 1 ,Here you can assign other roles ids
            ->setRoleUserId($user->getUserId())
            ->saveRelations();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

echo "User created successfully";
?>
```

Comment: It seems to work but get new error: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db_name.admin_assert' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `r`.*, `a`.`assert_type`, `a`.`assert_data` FROM `admin_rule` AS `r`
 LEFT JOIN `admin_assert` AS `a` ON a.assert_id = r.assert_id

Comment: Just checked. 2 tables are missing there: adminnotification_inbox and admin_assert

Comment: I uploaded these 2 tables from my local installation and it worked. thanks to you.

Comment: Yes, will do for sure.

Comment: I use magento 1.8, there is no table called "admin_rule" only "mageadmin_rule"

Answer (score 1):

Open your phpmyadmin from your host try once this sql command.
Run this Sql

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE core_store SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE core_store_group SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE core_website SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin'; 
UPDATE customer_group SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Now admin can able to login.
please follow this [admin page shows 404 page not found](http://tejabhagavan.blogspot.in/2015/12/after-install-magento-admin-page-shows.html)

Answer (score 0):

Change as per your need username is 'myuser' and password is 'password'
and don't forget to clear cache

simply, create new user:

```
LOCK TABLES `admin_role` WRITE , `admin_user` WRITE;

SET @SALT = "rp";
SET @PASS = CONCAT(MD5(CONCAT( @SALT , "password") ), CONCAT(":", @SALT ));
SELECT @EXTRA := MAX(extra) FROM admin_user WHERE extra IS NOT NULL;

INSERT INTO `admin_user` (firstname,lastname,email,username,password,created,lognum,reload_acl_flag,is_active,extra,rp_token_created_at) 
VALUES ('Firstname','Lastname','email@example.com','myuser',@PASS,NOW(),0,0,1,@EXTRA,NOW());

INSERT INTO `admin_role` (parent_id,tree_level,sort_order,role_type,user_id,role_name) 
VALUES (1,2,0,'U',(SELECT user_id FROM admin_user WHERE username = 'myuser'),'Firstname');

UNLOCK TABLES;
```